# "query" is not a valid Page export field - When Trying to deploy NextJS13 and Sanity.io to Vercel

Tags: node.js, reactjs, vercel, sanity, next.js13

I'm learning NextJS13 and was following a blog tutorial online by Sonny Sangha 'Let’s build a BLOG with Next.js 13 (Sanity v3, TypeScript, Tailwind CSS, Auth, CMS, Preview Mode)'. Upon completion of the tutorial, I want to deploy the site to Vercel, however im running into this issue:

> app/(user)/page.tsx
> "query is not valid Page export Field

The specific code for that page in question is here:

```js
import { groq } from "next-sanity";
import { client } from "../../sanity/lib/client"
import BlogList from "../../components/BlogList";

export const query = groq`
  *[_type == 'post'] {
    ...,
    author->,
    categories[]->,
  } | order(_createdAt desc)
`;

export default async function HomePage() {

  const posts = await client.fetch(query);
  return (
    <BlogList posts = {posts} />
  );
}
```

I tried getstaticprops but apparently thats outdated in nextjs13. And not sure how else I can query sanity.io without exporting the query (my first time ever building anything with nextjs). Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Just remove the `export` of `query`, so only the React Component (`HomePage`) is exported.

Comment: What if I want to export a component and a constant from a Page file? Is that not possible?